# Component not re-rendering after Redux-Saga call

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

My component shows incorrect value from store.
The request was successful and after request I've got `fetching: false` and contacts list in Redux state. But component doesn't update, `console.log(fetching)` shows `true` and UI shows "Loading".
In Redux dev tools there's only 'GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS' action.
Why component doesn't update, where can be the problem? Seems like I do everything as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614396/12994741

Component:

```
const { contacts, fetching } = useSelector(state => state.contact);

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST' });
}, [dispatch])

console.log(fetching);

return <div>
  {fetching
   ? <p> Loading </p>
   : (contacts.map(contact => <div key={contact.id}>{contact.id}</div>)}
  </div>
```

Saga:

```
function* getContactsSaga() {
  try {
    const response = yield call('...');

    if (response && response.data) {
      yield put({
        type: 'GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS',
        items: response.data,
      })
    } else {
      yield put({
        type: 'GET_CONTACTS_FAILED',
        message: 'Data Access Error. Please Try again later',
      });
    }
  } catch (e) {
    yield put({
      type: 'GET_CONTACTS_FAILED',
      message: e.response.statusText,
    });
  }
}

function* contactSaga() {
  yield takeLatest('GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST', getContactsSaga);
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  error: '',
  fetching: false,
  contacts: [],
};

const ContactReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: true,
      };
    case 'GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        error: '',
        fetching: false,
        contacts: action.items,
      };
    case 'GET_CONTACTS_FAILED':
      return {
        ...state,
        fetching: false,
        error: action.message,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're only seeing one action in the dev tools wouldn't it be `GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST` not `GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS`? Nothing looks obviously wrong to me so maybe check to make sure your root saga is hooked up to the store correctly and is actually being run when `GET_CONTACTS_REQUEST` is dispatched.

Comment: @azundo no, it really was ```GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS```.

I think it's just bad combination of Redux Saga + Redux Persist + Gatsby. I had to refuse to use Persist to make my store work correctly.